# Advice in design about Control Structure else if, switch o a better way?

Tags: php, if-statement

I made the script to do what is expected, so it work ok but there must be a more elegant way to achieve the same result. I know that using switch will make it look nicer but not sure if the result will be the same as the 'default:' behavior:

This is the section of the script i want to refactor:

```
foreach ($free_slots as $val) { // here i am looping through some time slots

    $slot_out = $free_slots[$x][1];
    $slot_in = $free_slots[$x][0];
    $slot_hours = $slot_out - $slot_in;                  

        // tasks

    if ($slot_out != '00:00:00') {                


        // Here i call a function that do a mysql query and
        // return the user active tasks

        $result = tasks($deadline,$user);
        $row_task = mysql_fetch_array($result);

        // HERE IS THE UGLY PART <<<<<----------------

        // the array will return a list of tasks where this current
        // users involved, in some cases it may show active tasks 
        // for other users as the same task may be divided between 
        // users, like i start the task and you continue it, so for 
        // the records, user 1 and 2 are involved in the same task.
        // The elseif conditions are to extract the info related
        // to the current $user so if no condition apply i need 
        // to change function to return only unnasigned tasks.
        // so the i need the first section of the elseif with the 
        // same conditions of the second section, that is where i
        // actually take actions, just to be able to change of  
        // change of function in case no condition apply and insert
        // tasks that are unassigned. 


        if ($row_task['condition1'] == 1 && etc...) {
        } else if ($row_task['condition2'] == 1 && etc...) {
        } else if ($row_task['condition3'] == 1 && etc...) {
        } else if ($row_task['condition4'] == 1 && etc...) {
        } else {

        // in case no condition found i change function
        // and overwrite the variables

            $result = tasks($deadline,'');
            $row_task = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        }

        if ($row_task['condition1'] == 1 && etc...) {

           // insert into database

        } else if ($row_task['condition2'] == 1 && etc...) {
           // insert into database
        } else if ($row_task['condition3'] == 1 && etc...) {
           // insert into database
        } else if ($row_task['condition4'] == 1 && etc...) {
        } else {
            echo 'nothing to insert</br>';
        }

    }            

}
```

Basically i run the else if block twice just to be able to change of function in case nothing is found in the first loop and be able to allocate records unassigned.

Comment: why not use another `foreach`?

Comment: Also, there's no way to help with logic when you use `&& etc...`.

Comment: for the second block of conditions? is not the same?

Comment: And, if I were you, I'd use `if ($slot_out != '00:00:00') {` and put all of the code, rather than have an empty if and then putting it all in else.

Comment: i wrote && etc.. as the conditions can be anything.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, i updated the question with your suggestion on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't changed the functionality of your code, but this is definitely a lot cleaner.

The main problem was that your logic for your if/else statements was confused. When you're writing:

```
if($a == 1){ } else if($b == 1){ } else if($c == 1){ }else{ //do something }
```

You're saying `If a is 1 do nothing, if b is 1 do nothing, if c is 1 do nothing, but if all of those did nothing, do something` when you can just say `if a is not 1 and b is not 1 and c is not 1, do something.`

I wasn't too sure on your second if statements, but generally it's not good to have an if else with no body within it. However, if the "insert into database" comment does the same thing, you can merge the 3 if statements that do the same code.

I hope i've cleared a few things up for you.

Here's what I ended up with:

```
foreach ($free_slots as $val) { // here i am looping through some time slots
    $slot_out = $free_slots[$x][1];
    $slot_in = $free_slots[$x][0];
    $slot_hours = $slot_out - $slot_in;                  

    // tasks
    if ($slot_out != '00:00:00') {
        $result = tasks($deadline, $user);
        $row_task = mysql_fetch_array($result);

        if (!($row_task['condition1'] == 1 || $row_task['condition2'] == 1 || $row_task['condition3'] == 1 || $row_task['condition4'] == 1)) {
            $result = tasks($deadline,'');
            $row_task = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        }

        if ($row_task['condition1'] == 1 && etc...) {
       // insert into database
        } else if ($row_task['condition2'] == 1) {
           // insert into database
        } else if ($row_task['condition3'] == 1) {
           // insert into database
        } else if ($row_task['condition4'] == 1) {

        } else {
            echo 'nothing to insert</br>';
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, indeed is more clean!

Comment: Could you elaborate on the second set, where the comment "// insert into database" is shown, do those all insert the same thing/run the same code?

Comment: Hey Daniel!, basically are the same mysql insert, just i add fixed values to titles and task ID depending of the condition found, that is why are different inserts, if condition 4 is found, by example, in the insert the title is sort of "Condition 4 found"